# Existe restrições na renderização de XML?

Tags: php, xml, web-service

Tenho um arquivo de 960 registros aonde cada registro tem 175 campos, é um formulário de imobiliária. Quando eu peço para fazer o loop dos 960 registros com apenas 10 campos ativados, ele gera um erro no XML conforme foto.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
// Loop dos valores
for ( $i = 0; $i<count($res)-1; $i++ ) {
    $xml .= '<Imovel>';

    $xml.="<DATA>".$res[$i]["Data cadastro"]."</DATA>";
    $xml.="<ENDERECO>".$res[$i]["Endereco"]."</ENDERECO>";
    $xml.="<BAIRRO>".$res[$i]["Bairro"]."</BAIRRO>";
    $xml.="<CIDADE>".$res[$i]["Cidade"]."</CIDADE>";
    $xml.="<UF>".$res[$i]["UF"]."</UF>";
    $xml.="<EMPREENDIMENTO>".$res[$i]["Empreendimento"]."</EMPREENDIMENTO>";
    $xml.="<NUMERO>".$res[$i]["Numero"]."</NUMERO>";
    $xml.="<PLACA>".$res[$i]["Referencia"]."</PLACA>";
    $xml.="<DORMITORIO>".$res[$i]["Dormitorio"]."</DORMITORIO>";
    $xml.="<SUITE>".$res[$i]["Suite"]."</SUITE>";
    ...
```

Já quando eu faço esse loop só para pegar o primeiro registro, ele retorna um **XML** válido. Existe restrições em relação a geração do **XML** ou pode haver erro nos dados?

Comment: Já pensou na possibilidade do parser do webservice ter alguma limitação no comprimento da linha? Esta passando todos os parâmetros conforme o manual? O servidor não tem nenhuma extensão para manipulação de XML, como o simplexml?

Comment: Ele não tem extensão para manipular o XML mas eu já encontrei uma solução: colocar tudo dentro de CDATA[] e assim busquei todos os registros normalmente. O CDATA[] influência no tempo de geração do arquivo XML? Pode me ajudar com esta pergunta também: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/31718/como-inserir-dados-xml-dentro-de-um-banco-mysql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não existe limitação, pela mensagem de erro o seu problema pode ser a presença de um `&` em algum campo.

Você pode tentar substituir todos os `&` que tiver por `&amp;`

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. Como eu poderia fazer isso em tempo de execução do script que monta o XML?

Comment: Eu realmente não entendo de PHP para te dizer exatamente o que fazer, mas seria basicamente dar um replace na hora de montar os campos em que pode ter este caractere

Comment: Sabe de algum método eficiente para retornar exatamente aonde está o erro do `XML` ou mostrar exatamente a localização do erro?

Comment: Acabei resolvendo com C_DATA[].