# Como inserir dados XML dentro de um banco MYSQL?

Tags: php, html, mysql, xml, dump

Gerando o arquivo `XML` com `PHP` recebo o seguinte resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu gostaria de mandar isso agora para um banco de dados `MYSQL` inserindo primeiro as colunas na tabela `Imovel` e depois preenchendo estas colunas com os dados que estão sendo puxados dentro de cada **field**.

Alguém poderia me ajudar a fazer um script para inserir dados do `XML` dentro do banco de dados `MYSQL`?

Comment: A pergunta é essa mesmo, ou você quer saber como extrair dados de um xml? Talvez seja melhor editar a pergunta e resolver um problema por vez para aumentar a possibilidade de boas respostas. Sugiro também uma lida aqui sobre como pegar dados do XML em PHP: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/15451

Comment: A pergunta é esta mesmo: Como pegar estes dados todos de primeiro nível e montar um `sql` pra colocar dentro do banco de dados? Os dados eu já os tenho, inclusive são dinâmicos montados através de uma consulta `PHP`. O resultado desta consulta está aqui: http://axitech.com.br/vista/xml2.xml com 175 campos por registro.

Comment: Então você já conseguiu extrair os dados do XML pelo PHP, só falta inserir no MySQL?

Comment: Na verdade eu estou dando voltas porque fiz perguntas que ninguém responde. Eu gerei o `xml` através de uma consulta em `php`. Então eu tenho estes dados em xml **http://axitech.com.br/vista/xml1.xml** e em forma de array no php **http://axitech.com.br/vista/index.php** ... Preciso saber o que vou usar para montar estes dados no meu banco.

Comment: "Na verdade eu estou dando voltas porque fiz perguntas que ninguém responde" Exatamente isto que eu estou tentando fazer você entender. O problema está nas perguntas, pois você em várias delas está misturando um monte de problemas diferentes. Primeiro de tudo, eu sugeriria: 1) identifique cada problema separadamente 2) tente resolver um passo por vez 3) pergunte individualmente cada passo, se não encontrar a solução para o problema. Estamos todos aqui para ajudar, mas primeiro você tem que se situar. Sugestão de leitura, para aproveitar melhor o site: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Comment: Não estou criando XML na mão, olha um pedaço do código: http://pastebin.com/bhTNpZt2 ... tem 960 registros com 175 campos cada registro. Então é isso aê que gera o xml. Por enquanto fiz o loop pro primeiro registro pra não pesar pra fazer as perguntas. XML que puxa instruções de um web-service.

Comment: Eu já li as suas perguntas, porém você realmente precisa entender como o site funciona. Da maneira que estão, só alguém fazendo o código por você, e este não é o jeito que a coisa funciona. Tente entender o que comentei anteriormente, que é o caminho para você melhorar as perguntas e o entendimento de cada passo, e ao mesmo tempo aumentar em muito sua chance de obter solução para cada um dos problemas. A quantidade de perguntas não é um problema aqui, a objetividade de cada uma sim. Na sua cabeça há uma visão do problema, para quem está lendo outra, por isso é necessária clareza ao perguntar.

Comment: Concordo com tudo que o @Bacco disse. *Regra de Ouro: imagine que você está tentando respender a pergunta"* . . . . Sabe ler em inglês? [***Writing the perfect question***](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) é o tutorial definitivo.

Comment: Pessoal, o que vocês não sabem **exatamente** é que eu sou iniciante, então eu preciso de um pouco de direção. Eu já criei várias coisas mas não sei a lógica para usá-las. Não sei se uso **xml**, se uso **php** ...

Comment: Você é iniciante em desenvolvimento de software ou de organizar ideias?

Comment: @MarcosViniciusNasc.Pereira, você tem uma coluna para cada campo? Li sua pergunta ontem mas você removeu na hora que estava respondendo... Seu XML poderia ser `<codigo>CL501</codigo><data>2012-03-16</data>...` Porque não tira o `CDATA`?

Comment: @PapaCharlie O `CDATA` é porque estou tendo problemas com caracteres especiais, então coloquei o `CDATA` visto que tenho extensos campos de `descricao` com textos.

Comment: Se não me engano o problema era com valores vazios como o campo 'Conservacao Imovel'. CDATA não vai converter a acentuação.

Comment: @PapaCharlie me ajuda nessa? http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/31736/como-realizar-as-consultas-via-web-service

Comment: @MarcosViniciusNasc.Pereira, eu respondi a questão, diga se gerou erro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recomendo você arrumar esse XML para uma forma mais pratica e evitar repetir os nodes. Repare que até seu `CDATA` contém espaços indevidos, para remove-los use a função *TRIM*
Talvez a melhor opção seja de XML para seu caso seja:

```
<CODIGO>CL501</CODIGO>
<DATA>2012-03-16</DATA>
```

Com o XML que você passou, o melhor que se pode fazer é da forma abaixo:

<sub>**XML**</sub>

```
$string = '<Imovel>
  <field name="CODIGO"><![CDATA[ CL501 ]]></field>
  <field name="DATA"><![CDATA[ 2012-03-16 ]]></field>
  <field name="ENDERECO"><![CDATA[ CASEMIRO DE ABREU ]]></field>
</Imovel>';
```

<sub>**Montando a SQL**</sub>

```
$root = simplexml_load_string( $string ); 

foreach( $root as $element )
{
    foreach( $element-> attributes() as $field )
    {
        $clear    = trim( $element );
        $fields[] = "'$field'";
        $values[] = "'$clear'";
    }
}
```

<sub>**SQL**</sub>

```
INSERT INTO `TABLE` (" . implode( ', ' , $fields ) . ")
             VALUES (" . implode( ', ' , $values ) . ")
```

<sub>**OUTPUT**</sub>

```
INSERT INTO `TABLE` ('CODIGO', 'DATA', 'ENDERECO')
             VALUES ('CL501', '2012-03-16', 'CASEMIRO DE ABREU')
```